# Iterating through a List<CustomClass> in jsp (jsp:getProperty?)

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I want to iterate through a List that is a member variable of a User object. 
I don't want to use snippets and would like to use some form of jsp tags to do the trick.

**User class**

```
public class User {

  private List<Option> options;

  public getOptions()...
}
```

**What I'm trying to do in snippets**

```
<%
User user = (User)session.getAttribute("user");
List<Option> options = user.getOptions();
%>

<select id="alertFilter">

<% for (Option o : options) { %>

<option><%=o.getTitle()%></option>

<% } %>

</select>
```

I've seen a few simple examples of what I'm trying to do but they always get simple ojects back.

**Tag Library way - not working**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<jsp:useBean id="user" class="ie.openmobile.smsjobs.entity.User" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>

<c:forEach var="options" items="$user.options" >   <--incorrect references to alerts/getOptions()

<br>$options.title   <--incorrect syntax

</c:forEach>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change it to as follows

```
<select id="alertFilter">

<c:forEach var="option" items="${user.options}" >
  <option><c:out value="${option.title}"/></option>
</c:forEach>

</select>
```

**Explanation** : ${user.options} will get the user from session and options collection using  its `getOptions()` method, and it will iterate on each entry

While under the iteration `${option.title}` would give the `option` ( which is the current option instance under traversal)  and `option.getTile()`

Comment: You sir, did help me 2 years later! :) Thanks a lot!