# How to populate data from servlet to dropdown

Tags: jsp, servlets, httpsession

I Have a servlet where i have returned a list :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("inside doPost of Role Management ---");
        this.context = request.getServletContext();
        UserProperties userProp;
        try{
            userProp= new UserProperties();
            //just a place holder to see if the property file can be read...
            userGroup_DS_Proxy = userProp.ReadProperties("UserGroup_DS_Proxy").toString();
            System.out.println("Properties file location was found in th tomcat folder");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            userProp= new UserProperties(context);
            System.out.println("Fail Safe Mode Activated");
        }
        userGroup_DS_Proxy = userProp.ReadProperties("UserGroup_DS_Proxy").toString();
        roleManagementDebug = Boolean.valueOf(userProp.ReadProperties("RoleManagementDebug").toString());
        RoleManagementDAO roleManagementDAO= new RoleManagementDAO(roleManagementDebug,userGroup_DS_Proxy);

        if(roleManagementDebug){
            System.out.println("new post for Role Management");
        }
        List<String> roles = roleManagementDAO.getRoles();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("RoleList", roles);
    }
```

Now i am passing the list by setting it in HttpSession as : 
**session.setAttribute("RoleList", roles);**

Now i want to get this session value in the jsp and populate a dropdown with this session variable.
Since i don't have much knowledge of JSP side, It is getting really hard for me to solve this problem. How can i do this? Looking forward to your answers.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can use jstl tag and display the list instead of trying with scriptlet (<% %>). In your header of jsp,

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" 
       uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342440/iterating-through-a-listcustomclass-in-jsp-jspgetproperty#11342467) for info.

```
<c:forEach var="listVar" items="${listName}">  //In your case RoleList 
     <option value ="${listVar.attribute1}">
           <c:out value="${listVar.attribute2}"/>
    </option>
</c:forEach>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For your information you can get the jstl library [here](http://search.maven.org/#browse|-1002239620) and jstl step by step tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vinoth. I am currently implementing your answer. Will inform you shortly.

Comment: I am not able to call the servlet. How can i call the servlet page and use the above code snippet?

Comment: You need to use the above code after your servlet got executed. Then only the session `RoleList` will be available. Let me know if you need any clarification required.